# Why am I getting this weird artifact when I display the ASP NET page in the web browser?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

The best way to display what I see is by giving you a couple of screenshots:
http://i150.photobucket.com/albums/s99/dc2000_bucket/scr1.jpg

http://i150.photobucket.com/albums/s99/dc2000_bucket/scr2.jpg

The link above also shows the html/asp code.

The question is why am I getting that white line when I render content in the web browser????

PS. I'm using VS2010 (that I am ready to smash with a hammer...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, guys, I got the bottom of it. The following style should be added to the  tag that hosts the image. I don't know why, but it helps:

td{ font-size:0; }

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

User [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), and everything should be solved. The reason you're getting the `weird artifact` is that, browsers by default apply some style on HTML elements. To nullify those default styles, designers usually use **CSS Reset**. A CSS Reset is a CSS file that tries to remove all default styles applied by browsers.

To debug your CSS margins and paddings, use Firebug with Firefox. Here is an image of how to do that:

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that the whole idea of resetting CSS is to place the CSS style sheet from the link you gave into my project and running it. If so, it didn't work...

Interesting observation. If I save the page, say from IE, onto my desktop and open it from there it looks *absolutely fine*. How would you explain that?

Comment: No, don't use that link directly. Browse to that link, get the CSS presented there, copy/paste it in a reset.css file on your computer, add that file to your project, and then use that file. :). Don't save the page, just copy/paste the CSS. That's all.

Comment: Yes, I did copy and paste CSS into my project. What I meant about saving is my page from my example. If I save it and open it from the hard drive (without ASP NET rendering) it looks fine.

Comment: It beats me... take a look:
http://i150.photobucket.com/albums/s99/dc2000_bucket/scr3.jpg

Comment: Well, examine all tags you got there. `table`, `tr`, `td`, `img`, `form`, `tbody` and almost any tag you have.

Comment: The body element itself had margins, I removed them but it simply moved the whole page up and to the left..... I give up. This is definitely not a browser's fault...... Maybe I should go to bed and try again tomorrow..........

Comment: A new morning... a new day... I thought tackling it with a fresh approach would work, but ... not this time.

Here's the actual project that I'm having issues with:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31368633/WebApp001.zip

Answer (score 1):

1. Images are inline elements.
2. Inline elements are rendered like characters.
3. Characters sit on a line.
4. There is space below that line for descenders (which you find on letters like g, j and y but not a, b, and c.)
5. That space is what you are seeing.

You could twiddle the [vertical-alignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height) of the images or [stop using layout tables](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)

Comment: The HTML for the table in my example works absolutely fine if I copy it into, say, DreamWeaver and run it from there. How would you explain that? Also please read my answer to the comment above yours.

Comment: Dreamweaver has a very poor preview view.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting the browser's default styling here. I would recommend grabbing a CSS reset and seeing if that helps

Comment: I doubt that any specific browser is here to blame, since all three independent browsers produced the same result. I'd be more inclined to blame whatever they use in VS2010 to emulate the IIS.

Comment: the server shouldn't affect it. How they are executing the code at design time (how they display that view) may be at fault, but that isn't related to IIS. Since Saeed's answer didn't help, I'd agree that it isn't browser specific